# How to write blade syntax in external js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Sorry for Typo mistakes.

I have a external js file there i want to use url() function by using blade syntax.

I am doing like below but it's not working

```
$.ajax({  
    url:"{!! url('/admin/dashboard/get-survey-details') !!}",
    method:"GET",
    data:"",  
    success:function(data)  
    {  
      //console.log(data);
      var res = data.split('~~');
      var dataarr = JSON.parse(res[0]);
      var dataarr2 = JSON.parse(res[1]);
      var dataarr4 = JSON.parse(res[3]);
      //console.log(dataarr);
    }
    ......
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's engine is not going to parse this file and associated blade tags unless you name this file `something.blade.php`.

Wrap your code into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
</script>
```

Give it a filename containing `.blade.php` and include into your template or view.

Comment: Thanks Serg Chernata. If i am doing by wrapping my code into <script> tag it's working but i wan't the same from external js.

Comment: Thanks Serg Chernata. Earlier i had wrapped my code in same blade now   i had done like suggested by you. Now it's working fine.